# How can I execute a query that can remove all at once the apostrophes in all data stored in my db?

Tags: mysql

I have here the select statement query, and shows a thousand values that have apostrophes.

```
Select * from tblProductList where Description like "% ' %";
```

I did try update some, but it's very time consuming if I did it one by one.

```
Update tblProductList set Description = "Mamas Hub" where Description = "Mama's Hub";
```

Comment: You could use SELECT INTO... to make a .csv file of your data for each table and use a simple script, or a text editor if the files are not so big, to remove apostrophes, delete all your tables' rows, then reload the modified data from the .csv files. This is pretty hazardous though so if the data is valuable, you might want to get someone to write a program for you.

Comment: Or you could UPDATE table SET field1 = replace(field1,'''',''), field2 = replace(field2,'''',''), ...fieldn = replace(fieldn,'''',''); and no WHERE clause so it applies to every column and row. You'll need an SQL command for each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `replace()` and `like`

```
Update tblProductList 
set Description = replace(Description, '''', '')
where Description like '%''%';
```

Strings are delimited by single quotes `'`, which can be duplicated to escape them so `''` implies `'` within the delimited string.

Comment: it actually worked sir, no need to do it individually in all data. Thanks!